# Why is $f(X)$ open or closed if $f:X\to\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ is regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I have a question about a certain property of regular maps into $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$. This is my notation for the affine space over $k$, algebraically closed.

Suppose $f:X\to \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ is a regular map, where $X$ is some algebraic set/subvariety in some affine space. I read that if $n=1$, then $f$ is sometimes called a regular *function*, and in this case, the image $f(X)$ is necessarily open or closed in $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$. [Edit: From the current answer, why is $f(X)$ necessarily open?]

Why does this property hold in particular for regular functions? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you now asking why the image is necessarily open? Georges explained exactly why!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I was just editing the question to make it more precise. I thought it had to be either open or closed, but it turns out it's just open. Also, I haven't read of Chevalley's theorem yet, so I'm wondering if there are more low-level explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the morphism $f$ is non-constant on at least one irreducible component of $X$, then its  image  $f(X)\subset \mathbb A^1(k)$ contains an open subset of $\mathbb A^1(k)$ (Chevalley's theorem) and is thus itself open, because the non-empty open subsets of  $\mathbb A^1(k)$ are the complements of finite subsets.

The result is false for maps into higher dimensional affine spaces, as witnessed by the morphism $$\mathbb A^2(k) \to \mathbb A^2(k): (x,y)\mapsto (xy, y)$$ whose image is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Georges, the function should be nonconstant one some irred component for this to work.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Mariano: I have edited my answer accordingly. Thanks a lot for your attentive reading.

Comment: Thanks Georges. If $f$ is constant on each irreducible component of $X$, is it fair to say $f(X)$ is a finite number of points, hence closed?

Comment: Yes,Tiffany, that's correct because a variety has only finitely many irreducible components.

Comment: You are welcome, Tiffany.